# Is there a way to map Google app script html template to a custom domain name?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am interested in working to develop an entire application on Google Apps script html template. Can I map a domain to the app script using Google Apps for Business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution for this is to host your Apps Script within a Google Sites page (which can be hosted at [subdomain].your-domain.com).

[Here's a little bit about GAS gadgets on Google Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets).

And [Google Sites on your own subdomain](http://support.google.com/sites/answer/99448?hl=en). Click the "Sites through Google Apps" dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **very** overdue response, but yes you can do this!

The crucial step is adding the .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) enum to your HtmlServe like so:

```
return HtmlService
     .createTemplateFromFile('login')
     .evaluate()
     .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Then you can simply take your Apps Script URL and embed it on any webpage you like. It even supports SSL if you have that enabled on your server.

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec"></iframe>
```

> Source:
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode